# how to test mnist on my own dataset images

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm trying to test mnist using my own dataset of digits images.
I wrote a python script for that but it is giving an error. error is in line no 16 of code. Actually i'm not able to send image for test. give me some suggestions. thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import caffe
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

caffe_root = '../caffe-master/'
MODEL_FILE = './examples/mnist/lenet.prototxt'
PRETRAINED = './examples/mnist/lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel'
IMAGE_FILE = '/home/hemant/OpenCVProject/grey/img001-00001.png'#image path

input_image = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)

net = caffe.Net(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED,caffe.TEST)
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
out = net.forward([input_image])
print out['prob']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the python wrapper class `Classifier`?

```
net = caffe.Classifier( MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED )
net.predict( [input_image], oversmaple=False )
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think LeNeT model expect gray scale image, you might need to read the image

```
input_image = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE, color=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import caffe
import os

model_file = '../examples/mnist/lenet.prototxt'
pretrained_file = '../examples/mnist/lenet_iter_10000.caffemodel'
net = caffe.Classifier(model_file, pretrained_file, image_dims=(28, 28), raw_scale=255)
score = net.predict([caffe.io.load_image('img/1.bmp', color=False)], oversample=False)
print score
```

This code work for me, the output is like that:

```
...
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```